# Using Angular (v4) AnimationBuilder makes width unresponsive

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-animations

`@angular/animations: v4.4.6`

My goal is to use `AnimationBuilder` to create a simple horizontal open and close animation. I have this mostly working except that the width of the element that is animated becomes fixed. Implementing the same animation with a trigger works as intended and the width remains responsive with different viewport sizes.

I have a running example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivlzma?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts).

As you can see, if you adjust the width of your viewport, the width of the div animated by the `AnimationBuilder` does not adjust responsively. But the width of the div that uses an animation trigger does.

How would I use the `AnimationBuilder` so that I get the exact same result as using the trigger?

You can see and edit the code in the above link, but I'll copy it below for reference:

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger, state, style, transition, animate, AnimationBuilder, AnimationPlayer } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  animations: [
    trigger('collapse', [
      state('open', style({ width: '*' })),
      state('close', style({ width: 0 })),
      transition('open => close', [
        style({ width: '*' }),
        animate(200, style({ width: 0 }))
      ]),
      transition('close => open', [
        style({ width: 0 }),
        animate(200, style({ width: '*' }))
      ])
    ])
  ]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit  {
  isOpen = true;
  get collapseState() {
    return this.isOpen ? 'open' : 'close';
  }
  @ViewChild('withBuilder') elementRef: ElementRef;
  private openPlayer: AnimationPlayer;
  private closePlayer: AnimationPlayer;

  constructor(private animationBuilder: AnimationBuilder) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.openPlayer = this.animationBuilder
      .build([
        style({ width: 0 }),
        animate(200, style({ width: '*' }))
      ])
      .create(this.elementRef.nativeElement);
    this.closePlayer = this.animationBuilder
      .build([
        style({ width: '*' }),
        animate(200, style({ width: 0 }))
      ])
      .create(this.elementRef.nativeElement);

    if (this.isOpen) {
      this.openPlayer.finish();
    } else {
      this.closePlayer.finish();
    }
  }

  toggle() {
    if (this.isOpen) {
      this.closePlayer.play();
      this.openPlayer.reset();
    } else {
      this.openPlayer.play();
      this.closePlayer.reset();
    }
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<button (click)="toggle()">Toggle</button>
<h2>Without AnimationBuilder:</h2>
<div class="container" [@collapse]="collapseState"></div>
<h2>With AnimationBuilder:</h2>
<div class="container" #withBuilder></div>
```

app.component.css

```
.container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`AnimationBuilder` uses `TimelineAnimationEngine` that does not handle element state. Full width size is fixed by the animation player that is still working.

As you can see collapse trigger from the annotations removes animation player and adds style="width: 0px".

Here is a working solution that directly handle element state. But it looks dirty. And it does not handle change direction cases (while prev animation is still playing)

```
@ViewChild('withBuilder') elementRef: ElementRef;

isOpen = true;

private closeAnimation: AnimationFactory;
private openAnimation: AnimationFactory;

constructor(private styler: StylerComponent,
    private animationBuilder: AnimationBuilder,
    private renderer: Renderer2) {
  this.openAnimation = this.animationBuilder
      .build([
        style({width: 0}),
        animate(200, style({width: '*'})),
      ]);
  this.closeAnimation = this.animationBuilder
      .build([
        style({width: '*'}),
        animate(200, style({width: 0})),
      ]);
}

toggle() {
  console.log('toggle', this.isOpen);
  const el = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
  let player: AnimationPlayer;
  if (this.isOpen) {
    player = this.closeAnimation.create(el);
    player.onDone(() => {
      this.renderer.setStyle(el, 'width', 0);
    });
  } else {
    this.renderer.removeStyle(el, 'width');
    player = this.openAnimation.create(el);
  }
  player.onDone(() => {
    player.destroy();
  });
  player.play();
  this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! This definitely works but it feels as if the builder is missing functionality if this is what is required. I might open an issue on github

Comment: @RichMcCluskey have you opened an issue on github ? couldn't find it. I think problem still exists in Angular 8, AnimationBuilder corrupts responsiveness of element.

Comment: @AntonTemchenko No I never got a chance to open the issue. I'm working at a new company that doesn't use Angular so I'm a little out of the loop now and I probably won't get to it, but feel free to open it up and reference this :)

Comment: @RichMcCluskey sure :) I've opened https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/33353
And I am using your solution for now. Thanks